# Does an inline map/reduce on Mongo block?

Tags: mongodb

I know that since map/reduce writes to a collection it needs to grab the global write lock, but if I set output to inline, doesn't this write to memory? It still seems to be grabbing the lock. Is this perhaps normal for Mongo 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With inline mode, the output is returned as a single document essentially, limiting you to the max document size, so you may be seeing a difference in behavior or response time  because you have a larger result being returned?

In terms of the locking, the Map/Reduce job can be thought of as many smaller operations (including writes).

First, there is a javascript lock so that only one thread can execute JS code at one point in time, so single threaded, at least for now. But most JS steps of the MR (e.g. a single map()) are very short and consequently the lock is yielded very often.

There are also several non-JavaScript operations that MapReduce performs that take locks:

- It reads from a collection (read lock yielded every 100 documents)
- It inserts documents into the temporary collection (write lock for a single write)
- It creates a final collection or merges into or replaces an existing collection (write lock)

Your inline mode removes the second two by having it as an in-memory map, so you shouldn't be seeing write locks, at least not for this job.  Could the locks be because of the JS ops or reads rather than writes perhaps?

Comment: oh, and for reference, most of this info is here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work#Howdoesconcurrencywork

Comment: Thanks - my map has some string compares which are probably quite slow and so that is probably slowing things down. Hoping that 2.2 will remove that single JS limit.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4258 is the one you want to watch - it's in the dev 2.1 branch, but does require the spidermonkey to v8 switch to work.  You can build the dev branch with v8 to try it out: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+with+V8